# Can recreating a new variable inside a timer object decrease performance?

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop, flash-cs6

Hey everyone so I was wondering if recreating a variable movie clip inside a timer object every time it's called could decrease performance or cause a MEMORY LEAK. This is how I have it set up right now:

```
private function addSwimPowerUp(e:TimerEvent):void 
{
    var newSwimPower:mcSwimPower = new mcSwimPower();
    stage.addChild(newSwimPower);
    aSwimPowerUpArray.push(newSwimPower);
}
```

I do that with all my timer objects in my game. Should i just declare the `var newSwimPower` a private variable?

Comment: You are confusing variable and objects. This is the variable: var newSwimPower:mcSwimPower and this is the object: new mcSwimPower(). The variable is just a memory reference while the object require CPU and memory to be built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new instance of something and then not doing anything with it will result in its eventual garbage collection. That is, if your code was this:

```
private function addSwimPowerUp(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    var newSwimPower:mcSwimPower = new mcSwimPower();
}
```

Then all of those new MovieClips will get cleant up.

With that said, you're adding those objects to the display tree as well asn an array. If you do not remove the object from *both* of those things, it will not get garbage collected and that will be a memory leak.

Creating a class level variable for `newSwimPower` and assigning to that instead won't make any difference, other than that if you don't garbage collect the class referencing it then the last instance you created will still be in memory.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much for the information. I will definitely remove all instances of it.